# Other predictive methods than DL

Tags: cricket, icc, interruption, duckworth-lewis

I would like to know if the ICC  is considering other predictive methods than orthodox Duckworth-Lewis to arrive at a result in an interrupted cricket match?

Comment: I would suggest you to re-phrase the question as "better" is subjective. You can go through the [FAQ section](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not any current news for this; you will find some references like [this one](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/2012/may/29/icc-duckworth-lewis-method),
but the case is that these are not yet officially quoted by ICC so it is hard to believe such stuff.

Also [here](http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/icc-decides-to-keep-duckworth-lewis-drs-jayadevan-bouncers-powerplays/20120601.htm) is a news article which says they are continuing with DL.

Well in the race of other methods the one which is considered was [VJD method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadevan%27s_system).

But as noted in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadevan%27s_system), the ICC still uses the Duckworth-Lewis method in all international matches. The Jayadevan system has been put before the ICC in the past, but the decision was made to retain the Duckworth-Lewis method. The ICC will address the issue again at its next meeting in Dubai.
And the page was modified on 17th March 2013.